# Trigger local notification set from scheduleLocalNotification

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

In our app, if a user has set a reminder from us for the future, we set a local notification via,

```
UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
if (localNotif == nil) return;
NSDate *fireTime = [[NSDate date] addTimeInterval: 60 * 60]; // adds 1 hour (60 seconds * 60 minutes)
localNotif.fireDate = fireTime;
localNotif.alertBody = @"Alert!";

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
```

Obviously this is easy to test if it's just a few seconds / minutes, but to test 100% when it's scheduled for far in the future, for us to test that, is our only option to just wait?

On Android, you're able to simply adjust the date and time of the phone, and that triggers the local notification, but thus far, I can't see any way to do it on iOS.

Is there a way to?

Comment: What do you mean, you can't fine a place where you can change the device time or the local notification isn't fired for you ? How did you test it, was the app opened at foreground, was it at background or killed completely, did you re-install the app between the notification was set and supposed to be triggered ?

Comment: From within the app, set the time for "now" plus a time (an hour, for instance), then go to settings, adjust time to an hour and a minute in the future, and back to the gone screen. But no notification. If I wait an hour, however, I get one.

Comment: How do you configure the notification object and how exactly do you change the device time (same timezone or timezone shift + clock change) ?

Comment: I've updated my question to include the whole code for the notification.  To change the time on the device, Settings -> General -> Date & Time.  Uncheck "Set Automatically", leave timezone as it was (Dublin), tap time and roll hour and minute 1 ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the [timeZone](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UILocalNotification/timeZone) property of the `UILocalNotification`. Otherwise, the notification is simply a countdown timer.

```
localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
```